# Form Fields not available in Internet Explorer 11 and Edge

Tags: coldfusion, fusebox

A login form is submitted and when I try and dump the values the form structure is empty in IE but not FF or Chrome. This is in a DEV environment using HTTPS and a corporate self signed certificate.

I don't really think this is Fusebox related but it is the framework I'm using. No choice in the matter as it is legacy code and no budget to change it so please don't suggest I move on.

I've discovered that in IE it doesn't like the form action to be of the format:

```
/directory/index.cfm?fuseaction=app.Security
```

Instead it wants a fully qualified action

https://www.mycompany.com/directory/index.cfm?fuseaction=app.Security

```
<form action="/directory/index.cfm?fuseaction=app.Security" name="loginForm" id="loginForm" method="post">
  <div style="width:55%;" align="center" id="fieldset">
    <fieldset class="border" style="width:70%;">
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <div style="padding:2%">
            <label for="userID">User ID: <span id="error1" class="redbold" aria-live="assertive"></span> </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="required">*</span>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="userID" id="userID" size="32" maxlength="8" value="" />
        </div>
        <div style="padding:2%">
            <label for="pw">Password: <span id="error2" class="redbold" aria-live="assertive"></span></label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="required">*</span>&nbsp;<input type="password" name="pw" id="pw" size="32" maxlength="20" value="" />
        </div>
        <div style="padding:2%" id="formButtons">
            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="buttonfield" title="Login to eAgenda" />
            <span style="padding-left:5%; margin-left:5%">
                <input type="reset" value="Clear" class="buttonfield" title="Clear" />
            </span>
            <div id="errorMsg">
                <p>
                    <span class="redbold"></span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="required">*</span>Mandatory field
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can we see the code for your form? What version of IE are you using?

Comment: Updated as requested.

Comment: Your `form` tag doesn't close.

Comment: @Alex The final tag wasn't indented enough, so it wasn't visible.  Fixed.

Comment: @Smoketx Use the IE developer tools to check if the POST request contains the expected form data (network tab).

Comment: *it wants a fully qualified action* Does it work when you supply one? *"don't really think this is Fusebox related"* To verify that, temporarily take fusebox out of the mix. Create a small (isolated) test and action page. Are the results are the same?  FWIW, the code above worked with a non-https script and IE11.

Comment: @Smoketx Which page you have dump the form fields? Have you dump the correct location?

Comment: @SathishChelladurai I dumped them in the primary CFC that gets loaded. The dump is fine in FF or Chrome but empty in IE.

Comment: @Smoketx Have you use the abort after dumping in the CFC file? Mostly we should use abort after dump the variable. Mostly Its no needed to use the abort for the .cfm

Comment: @Ageax that worked. Now going back to the servers and having SSL requirements rolled back and putting production code in place to see if it works locally. Thanks for the suggestions folks. When I hit a solution I'll post it here.

Comment: Yes @SathishChelladurai I've been coding in CF for 20 years. I understand the basics. But thank you.

Comment: Sorry @Smoketx I didn't notice your profile. OK. If you hit the solution please post it here. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In the end it was a `<base href="http://..."/>` tag in the header. Removing or making it https solved the problem.

Comment: More info on `<base>` tag here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/what-are-the-recommendations-for-html-base-tag